# How Google decided how websites will look to my visitors?

Tags: google, google-search-console, wordpress, css

I have a small WordPress website, Google shows me a print screen of how the visitors of my site see it :

[image]

And as you can see in the image on the right, it seems like all the thumbnails gone and the site is squeezed to the right.

When I enter the site, everything looks great (like in the picture on the left).

How can I understand what is the problem, and fix it?

Comment: It is not clear what rendering engine Google uses for this. We know what rendering engine is used for Chrome, but not Google Search Console (the app formerly known as Google Webmaster Tools). Companies do not like to duplicate work and Google is very good at reusing technology and pushing the envelope by rolling their own. It is likely that a similar rendering engine as used in Chrome is used here. Have you tried your site using the *latest* version of Chrome??

Comment: It just occurred to me. Check your log file to make sure that Google is able read the images. This looks like a situation where the images were not downloaded in time or at all. Check to see if your images were downloaded. I suggest using Chrome and using the Developer Tools and check the waterfall graph to make sure that image download times are good. Also, if JS is serving the images or any scripting is in the process, it is possible that the JS has failed to trigger or run in the rendering engine or failed to provide images quick enough. Also, try this again in a bit.

Comment: I use the latest version of chrome, and tested the site on many computers and OS's. which log file are you talking about ?

Comment: I am talking about your web server log file. Make sure your images are being accessed properly. You should see a 200 success code. If you are using JS or other code to serve your images, it is possible that the rendering engine cannot run your code for some reason. Check it thoroughly.

Comment: It is not the problem, if you look closely you'll see he actually loaded the images but they are very small.

Comment: I guess the next natural question is how are they sized? Assuming of course that they are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is with your responsive design, and more specific - your breaking points. You can easily see that your website actually look exactly like the screenshot on 1024px width (see http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://www.wetravel.co.il/|1024|768|1) or just minimize your browser's width, you'll see the breaking point eventually). Google test the Desktop version on 1024px so that's the reason to display it like that. Your site looks like that for resolutions between 978px and 1186px. You should check your CSS, as that's the place where your problem occure

Comment: no problem :) I am happy you left the name of the site in your screenshot, so i was able to debug it :) Hope you fix it easily.

Comment: Actually I wrote the name of the site in the original question and someone edited it out :( I don't really understand how to fix it because i didn't wrote the wordpress theme, if while debugging you saw something that can direct me to the problem i would be happy to know. Thanks

Comment: actually i didn't saw something specific, if i have more time this weekend i will take a look on it.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find the problem, i'll post it as a question in the site