# My site breaks on specific resolutions

Tags: wordpress, css

It is all started here : [How Google decided how websites will look to my visitors?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83516/how-google-decided-how-websites-will-look-to-my-visitors/83565?noredirect=1#comment100056_83565)

Google told me that my site looks bad for my visitors [image]

and "Barnettt" answered me that it is happening in specific resolutions :

> " Your site looks like that for resolutions between 978px and 1186px.
>   You should check your CSS, as that's the place where your problem
>   occure"

It was easy to reproduced it just by resizeing chrome, but I've couldn't find what was the issue that causes it.

I'm not a great webdeveloper (actually i'm c++ developer), and i've tried to find out using chrome's debugging console what makes the site break, but couldn't.

If someone could take a look and point me to what might be the problem, I'll be extremely helpful.

my site address is : www.wetravel.co.il

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i got it. It seems there is conflict between your main CSS and a plugin or theme function for the rtl display.
Remove this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
    float: right;
}
}
```

from your rtl.css file

```
http://www.wetravel.co.il/wp-content/themes/tdmacro/rtl.css
```

This seems to be the conflict. It may not be the cleanest solution, but it's a fast and easy fix.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. can you elaborate please in a few words why this lines caused the problem and the lines above : @media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
  float: right;
 }
} 
didn't